# Тестирование websocket в spring boot

Tags: тестирование, spring-boot, spring-websocket

Хочу написать тесы для контроллера websocket, но ни один пример из сети у меня не вызывает методы из контроллера.
Кто уже имеет опыт написания таких тестов прошу показать пример.

Контроллер:

```
@Controller
public class SectionContoller {

    @Autowired
    private ISectionService sectionService;

    @MessageMapping("/section/add")
    @SendToUser
    public Message addSection(EntitySection section){
        sectionService.addSection(section);

        return MessageBuilder
            .withPayload("")
            .setHeader(HEADER_STATUS,STATUS_OK)
            .build();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**
Я пробовал подключиться к серверу websocket используя [этот](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#websocket-stomp-client) способ, но в логах подключение не выводилось, мб есть какая то тонкость использования спрингового Websocket клиента?

Comment: что именно вы хотите протестировать? опишите тест словами.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman метод `addSection` должен вызваться и вернуть сообщение. Я просто не могу понять каким образом тестировать контролеры для websocket.

Comment: это же просто метод. вызовите его в тесте и проверьте результат.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman я хочу что бы он вызвался когда отправляется сообщение на `/app/section/add`.

Comment: то есть вы хотите интеграционный тест? с запуском браузера и пр?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman я немного пошерстил документацию Spring и там есть возможность отправлять сообщения без использования браузера, но у меня не получилось заставить это работать.
Пробовал это - https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio/tree/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/samples/portfolio/web

И это https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-client

Comment: я просто пытаюсь понять, что именно вы тестируете. поэтому задаю наводящие вопросы. попробуйте определиться, что вы точно хотите протестировать. как работает ваш контроллер? как работе ваше приложение в целом? или что-то другое.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman я делаю для корсовой работы простой форум с разделами->подразделами->темами и сообщениями в них.
Пользователи могут регистрироваться и авторизироваться (это я сделал), создавать темы и оставлять в них сообщения.

 Этот контроллер должен будет отвечать за создание, удаление, получение раздела\подраздела по его имени или сразу все.
Сейчас я хочу отправить сообщение для создания раздела через тест и проверить что раздел создан.

Comment: не важно для чего вы делаете. важно, что вы хотите сделать! как вы хотите отправить сообщение? что вы конкретно проверяете? например, у вас онлайн калькулятор. вы хотите проверить сложение. вы можете проверить его  интеграционным тестом - полностью повторяя работу пользователя, или может просто вызвать метод контроллера, или вызвать сервис. все это будут разные тесты. определитесь, что вам нужно.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman я хочу с делать интеграционный тест: подключение к серверу через websocket-> подписание на "событие"-> отпарвка сообщения с данными -> добавление записи в базу данных-> ответ о статусе(выполнено или ошибка).

Comment: тогда смотрите в сторону Selenium, PhantomJs и пр. это будет не очень надежно и не очень просто, но особого выбора нет.

Comment: Да зачем же тут Selenium-ы и безголовые броузеры то? Нужен клиент вебсокетный всего то навсего. Если хочется писать на Java, то нужен такой клиент, написанный на Java. Я же обычно все HTTP и websocket интерфейсы тестирую с помощью Node.js + Jasmine. Там это значительно удобнее и быстрее.